# Look for a second carriage return using InDesign Grep

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I am looking for a *grep* expression for InDesign.

I have the following lines:

```
This is Line 1
This is Line 2
This is Line 3
This is Line 4
This is Line 5
This is Line 6
```

Line 1 and 2 will be right indent. 
Line 3 and 4 will be left indent. 
Line 5 and 6 will again be right indent.

There is a carriage return after each line, except line six.
I want to target the carriage return after line 2, 4 and replace it with some other character or forced linebreak.
How can I do that in grep?

Comment: Do you really mean carriage return or do you mean line feed or both? Please [edit] your question to show the output of `cat -Ev file` when tun on  your input file so we can see the carriage return and/or line feed characters

Comment: ("grep InDesign" - *"InDesign's built-in grep function."*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what: `(.+\r.+)\r`

Change to: `$1#`

where `#` is your symbol.